# Как сравнивать?

Tags: сравнение

здравствуйте. скажите пожалуйста с чем надо сравнивать худшее, если хочешь сказать про него еще хуже, с худшим или с лучшим? спасибо.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Хотя бы на примерах.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно поняла, речь идет о том, что мы имеем "тупой и еще тупее")))) То есть, есть у нас тупой, а есть тот, кто тупее этого тупого. То есть, сравниваем все-таки худшее с плохим.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я также думаю, просто поспорили с товарищем. решили спросить у филологов. спасибо